# VBA Power Point WebBrowser Works only once

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working on powerpoint addin in VBA. It should insert new slide with webbrowser - this works. Problem is when i try to navigate this control to web url. When i try first time and then enter in presentation mode - it works. When i try second time i get an exception and webbrowser is not displaying website :

code : (this works only once before presentation mode, after that when i try to run it again  i recive an error)

```
Sub creteUrls()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim sha As Shape
    Dim tempSh As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL$
        For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each sha In sld.Shapes
                For i = 4 To ActivePresentation.CustomXMLParts.Count
                    Set tempSh = sha
                        If tempSh.Name = CStr(ActivePresentation.CustomXMLParts(i).SelectNodes("webbrowser/name").item(1).Text) Then
                            URL = CStr(ActivePresentation.CustomXMLParts(i).SelectNodes("webbrowser/url").item(1).Text)
                            tempSh.OLEFormat.Object.Navigate URL, 4
                        End If
                    Set tempSh = Nothing
                Next i
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

[image: exception]